# Sass Error when trying to compile CSS of a map using @each function

Tags: css, sass

Im trying to create a series of classes for defining the styles for an image based on a skill. The skills and the associated color are created in a map.

```
$skills-color: (
    default     : #D8D8D8,
    6           : #2E80EC,
    5           : #E0102A,
    8           : #164242,
    11          : #2D882D,
    10          : #F8E71C,
    9           : #2A1E4B,
    sales       : #00FFFF,
    7           : #2ECC32
);
```

It runs though the following @each

```
@each $skill, $color in $skills-color {
    .#{$skill}-small {
        box-shadow:
        0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
        0 0 0 5px $color;
    }
    .#{$skill}-med {
        box-shadow:
        0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
        0 0 0 6px $color;
    }
    .#{$skill}-large {
        box-shadow:
        0 0 0 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
        0 0 0 8px $color;
    }
}
```

This worked fine when all the map 'keys' where words rather than a number

This is the error:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after ".": expected class name, was "6-small"
```

Note: I tried adding the keys in '1', '2', '3' etc but to no avail.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't believe that a css class name starting with a number is valid. Perhaps try appending a letter to the front of all the rows in the list to see if that helps.

Cheers.

Comment: wow! I think I'll have to re-address the basics. Thank you, you've saved me a lot of head scratching

Comment: Solid. Glad that helped.